# Overriding exception handling in spring

Tags: java, spring

I am finding difficulty in overriding Spring's exception handling. I want to throw "401 exception", but somehow Spring is throwing "500 internal server exception".

**Code:**

```
@ControllerAdvice
class ExceptionHandlerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public Response toResponse(Exception e) {
        return Response.status(401).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: post stacktrace of your server 500 error.

Comment: Add `HttpServletRequest request` as param. Example: `public Response toResponse(Exception e, HttpServletRequest request)`

Comment: Can you please post error response that you are getting?